# How can I use Magic: gradientview in Maui if I am migrating my code from Xamari?

Tags: xamarin.android, maui, gradient, migrating

I am migrating from xamarin to maui, but I have a problem with the MagicGradient package, I don't know how to use magic:GradienteView in Maui and I only get an error "The type 'magic:GradienteView' was not found. Check that a reference is not missing to an assembly and that all referenced assemblies have been compiled."

Comment: Maui has native gradient support - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/gradient?view=net-maui-8.0